# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined even though component isn't called yet

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

One of the pages in an app I'm currently building is a 'Category' page. It renders a table of rows from a particular category. These rows also have comments on them.

| col x | col y | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- |
| row1 x | row1 y | view |
| row2 x | row1 y | view |

I'm using react redux, when I go to a 'Category' page, no comments have been added to state yet, only the relevant rows to the category have been added (their comments are in a different table in my database. I am trying to make a component (the 'view' button) that will open up a dialog where the comments for the chosen row are fetched and displayed.

The problem is that as soon as I go to the Category page, I get the error in my title (the error pointing to the map function I've starred below)

```
class MyComments extends Component {
  state = {
    open: false,
    oldPath: "",
    newPath: "",
  };

  handleOpen = () => {
    let oldPath = window.location.pathname;

    const { categoryId, rowId } = this.props;
    const newPath = `/categories/${categoryId}/row/${rowId}`;

    if (oldPath === newPath) oldPath = `/categories/${categoryId}`;

    window.history.pushState(null, null, newPath);

    this.setState({ open: true, oldPath, newPath });
    this.props.getRow(this.props.rowId);
  };
  handleClose = () => {
    window.history.pushState(null, null, this.state.oldPath);
    this.setState({ open: false });
    this.props.clearErrors();
  };
  render() {
    const {
      row: { comments },
      UI: { loading },
    } = this.props;
    const commentsDialog = loading ? (
      <div>
        <CircularProgress size={200} thickness={2} />
      </div>
    ) : (
      <List>************
        {comments.map((comment) => (
          <ListItem>{comment.body}</ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>***********
    );
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Button onClick={this.handleOpen}>
          <UnfoldMore color="primary" />
        </Button>
        <Dialog
          open={this.state.open}
          onClose={this.handleClose}
          fullWidth
          maxWidth="sm"
        >
          <Button onClick={this.handleClose}>
            <CloseIcon />
          </Button>
          <DialogContent>{commentsDialog}</DialogContent>
        </Dialog>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

MyComments.propTypes = {
  clearErrors: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  getRow: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  rowId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  row: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  UI: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  row: state.data.row,
  UI: state.UI,
});

const mapActionsToProps = {
  getRow,
  clearErrors,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(MyComments);
```

One thing you might notice is that I push to a new url when the dialog is opened. One thing I did to debug this was I commented out the comments.map above (surrounded by *'s), then I was able to click on the dialog without error and go to the new url. once on the url, I changed my code back to the comments.map, and they displayed in a list in the dialog. So my problem is, my app is trying to render these options before they have been added to my state. I guess I'm wondering why my app cares about this map function before the dialog has opened?

My 'getRow' function returns a json as below so that's not the problem, I've console logged it to make sure the data is being fetched correctly, between this and what I just said above, I dont think that my actions or reducers are the problem, so I didnt add them but let me know if theyre relevant.

```
{
    "categoryId": "id",
    "index": "2",
    "body": "New test",
    "disapproveCount": 0,
    "approveCount": -1,
    "createdAt": "2021-03-05T23:16:26.142Z",
    "rowId": "id",
    "comments": [
        {
            "index": 2,
            "body": "hello",
            "rowId": "id"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've had this problem for about a week but I finished everything else first as I couldn't figure it out and also thought it would be too difficult to explain on stackoverflow. I hope this makes some sort of sense, still don't know if im explaining it correctly/fully so I'll be very grateful/surprised with any suggestions.

Also, ideally I would just like to display these comments not in a dialog, so that no buttons need to be pressed to see them, but I was having this problem before I tried a dialog, and I thought loading a dialog and on a new url would fix the problem, i.e., the options wouldn't be attempted to be rendered until I opened this new page/url

This could possible be relevant:

Category page (called document)

```
class document extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const categoryId = this.props.match.params.categoryId;
    this.props.getCategory(categoryId);
  }

  render() {
    const categoryId = this.props.match.params.categoryId;

    const { category, loading } = this.props.data;
    let placeholder = !loading ? (
      <div>
        <center>
          <h1>{categoryId}</h1>
          <h1> </h1>
        </center>

        <br></br>
        <Paper>
          <TableContainer>
            <TableHead>
              (...)
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
              {category.map((row) => (
                <TableRow key={row.rowId}>
                   (...)
                  <TableCell align="left">
                    <MyComments rowId={row.rowId} categoryId={categoryId} />
                  </TableCell>
                       (...)
              </TableRow>
              ))}
            </TableBody>
          </TableContainer>
        </Paper>
        <br></br>
        <MyForm categoryId={categoryId} />
      </div>
    ) : (
      <p>Loading...</p>
    );
    return <div>{placeholder}</div>;
  }
}

document.propTypes = {
  getCategory: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  data: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  data: state.data,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getCategory })(document);
```

I'm not sure if this is the exact problem, but I think a Tl;Dr is: why does the map function in my dialog care about something undefined when it hasn't been called yet?
Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place a ? symbol after the object key. It will check if the object key's value is undefined or null before proceeding further.

---

```
  <List>
    {comments?.map((comment) => (
      <ListItem>{comment.body}</ListItem>
    ))}
  </List>
```

---